# Log4Net Configuration - No system Log file created

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I'm having trouble getting log4net to create the log file when errors are recorded.

I'm using ninject to inject dependancies for my objects related to log4net, as ive created a wrapper:-

```
public interface ILogManager
{
   ILog GetLog(Type typeAssociatedWithRequestLog);
}

public class LogManagerAdapter : ILogManager
{
   public ILog GetLog(Type typeAssociatedWithRequestLog)
   {
      var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeAssociatedWithRequestLog);

      return log;
   }
}
```

In NinjectConfigurator.cs :-

```
 private void ConfigureLog4net(IKernel container)
 {
     XmlConfigurator.Configure();

     var logManager = new LogManagerAdapter();

     container.Bind<ILogManager>().ToConstant(logManager);
 }

 private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
 {
     ConfigureLog4net(container);
 }
```

In my webconfig i have the following :-

```
<configSections>
    <section name ="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\\..\\logs\\WebApi2Book.Api.Log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
      <countDirection value="1"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
      <logger name="NHibernate">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
      </logger>
      <logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
      </logger>
      <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
      </root>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

In the Global.asax class, Im testing the logger is actually being injected correctly and then testing logging an error in the Application_Start() method.

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            var log = WebContainerManager.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog(typeof(WebApiApplication));

            log.Error("Yey!!!!  works!");
            log.Debug("Yey!!!!  works!! Debug");


        }
```

I cant find any problems when i debug the program, i've checked that **IsDebugEnabled** is set as TRUE, and the logger in injected correctly as expected.

The only issue is that the log file isn't generated.

Comment: try an absolute path for the log file and make sure the user that runs your web application has permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in your root logger you are referencing an appender called "LogFileAppender" but in fact your appender is called "RollingFileAppender" - the appender name must be the same on both places:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  …
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender "/>
</root>
```